# undefined method `follow' from User.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

Rails 3.2 newb.

The app is twitter.

UPDATE 3: Progess has been made. I changed `@phriends` to `:phriends` in `buddies.html.erb`, now the notice `user don't exist` automatically comes up.. but at least the page loads.. then "Add/Subtract" gives me `"No route matches [POST] "/buddies"`

Update 2: `"undefined method`model_name' for NilClass:Class"` for @phriends... I don't think rails likes that I'm doing a lot on one page.

Update: `"Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id"`
I gotten this error twice two different times.

This comes from my User.rb model

```
  def following? user
self.followeds.include? user
 end

 def follow user
Relationship.create follower_id: self.id, followed_id: user.id
 end

 def unfollow user
   Relationship.destroy follower_id: self.id, followed_id: user.id
 end
```

To my user_controller.rb

```
def buddies
@phriends = User.find_by_username(params[:username])

                if current_user.following? @phriends
                        current_user.unfollow @phriends 
                        else
                    current_user.follow @phriends 
                    end
```

To views/user/buddies.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @phriends do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :username, placheholder:"username" %>
<%= f.submit "Add/Subtract" %>
```

As you can tell, I'm trying to follow/unfollow by typing in the correct username.

I have a feeling I'm wrong because that doesn't work.

Another options for the controller is this...

```
 @phriends = User.find_by_username(params[:username])  
                if current_user.following? @phriends
                        relationship_path, method: :delete
                        else
                    @relationship
                    end

                 @relationship = Relationship.where(
                                  follower_id: current_user.id,
                                   followed_id: @user.id
                                  ).first_or_initialize if current_user
```

But then it complains i don't got an ID.. can't crack this last problem.

This is an all-in-one page btw..breaking the rules a bit.

P.S. Extra Credit: This page also displays all the tweets i follow... how could I say, display only the most recent tweet per user...?

Comment: is it a problem in `user_controller.rb` that it does not know method `follow`?

Comment: I don't know if that's how it should be, but yes. I copied that from the tutorial.

Comment: Update & fixed original error. Now i get "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id" I've gotten this twice in two different setups.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem only in undefined method in controller then it is easy - you should call method from `current_user`

```
def buddies
  @phriends = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  if @phriends
    if current_user.following? @phriends
      current_user.unfollow @phriends
    else
      current_user.follow @phriends
    end
  else
    # @phriends is nil do smth for example
    flash[:notice] = "User with username #{params[:username]} is not found"
  end
end
```

Update: be careful because code `@phriends = User.find_by_username(params[:username])` can return nil and you can get `nil.some_method`. You can add checking if `@phriends` is not nil

PS `nil` in ruby means the same as `false` for boolean values

Comment: Just fixed at the same time, your right. Now i get. "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id"

Comment: Thanks, can someone explain this further?

Comment: As I understand you have some input or select on the page and user enter/select `username`. You find user using `find_by_username`. If such user can't be find then nil will be returned to variable `@phriends`. If you have nil user then you can not do follow/unfollow. I think you should define some message (for example flash) and display it to page (inform current_user that action follow/unfollow is not performed)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to figure this out earlier. I need a way to validate no blanks and presence true... so inside that `@phriends`if-statement I should say: `if @phriends = nil , notice: "User don't exist"` Does that cover all possible errors tho?

Comment: the method in controller can be as described above (I update it).